# How to install a npm package while ignoring one of its dependencies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I am working on an AWS SAM serverless project, on a Lambda function written in Node.js.

The Lambda execution environment already provides the AWS SDK, this it is not necessary to push this dependency into the deployment.

The problem arises when `aws-sdk` comes up as a nested dependency of another package.

For instance, I need `aws-appsync`, which depends in turn on `aws-sdk`.
Because of that, the deployment size is too big. The entire `aws-appsync` package with its dependency weights about 140mb, a notable portion of it being the AWS SDK. In this situation, the maximum deployment size is exceeded and the deployment procedure fails.

Can I make npm install a package with all its dependencies except a specific one? I would exclude `aws-sdk` from the dependencies in this case.

Comment: Are you saying the total unzipped deployment size exceeds 250MB?

Comment: How are you packaging up the Lambda?

Comment: Serverless Framework has plugins that solve this. Not sure if there are equivalent ones for SAM.

Comment: By some strange conditions, a full clean and dependency re-fetch shrinked the total package size. For this project, there is no packaging process.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution for this is to add the aws-sdk as a `devDependencies` instead of a normal dependency. You can the run `npm i --production` in your deployment pipeline before bundling the code and uploading it. This will ensure that the `devDependencies` are not available in the node_modules. (I don't think it will remove them if they are there already, so if you're doing it locally, you might have to delete the node_modules folder before running the npm command)